# Should I add "counterparts" to the end of this paragraph?

Tags: ellipsis, coordination

I am writing an introduction:

> Humanities courses are very useful to students. Yet, in my opinion, schools should focus more on science and mathematics courses. The benefits of these courses vastly exceed the convenience of humanities courses. There are main three advantages for mathematics courses over humanities.

Should I add *counterparts* to the end of the paragraph?

Answer (score 2):

It should be

> There are three main advantages for mathematics courses over their humanities counterparts

As it stands, you are comparing courses in mathematics to humanities as a subject, and not just humanities courses. So yes, counterparts would be relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

Biker of the apocalypse has correctly pointed out a comparability problem that occurs if *counterparts* is left out.  (Note, my personal preference is for *versus* rather than *over* in the context of Biker's example and your own.  With *over*, I'd use a different construction, illustrated later.)

However, another comparability problem then occurs:  use of *counterparts* suggests that for each mathematics course there is a corresponding humanities course.  But generally there is no such correspondence.  For that reason, I suggest not using the word  *counterparts*, and instead just repeat the word *courses*.  Eg,

> There are three main advantages for mathematics courses versus humanities courses.
>   *–or–*
>   Mathematics courses have three main advantages over  humanities courses.